# Can PCA or Principal component regression reveal information not seen in the univariate case?

Tags: r, pca

I am wondering if there is a case where you see something in the principal components (PC) what you do not see by looking univariately at the variables that the PCA is based on. For instance, considering the case of group differences: that you see a separation of two groups in one of the PCs, but not in a single variable (univariate).

I will use an example in the two dimensional setting to better illustrate my question: Lets suppose we have two groups, A and B, and for each observations we have two multivariate-normal distributed covariables.

```
# First Setting: 
group_A <- mvrnorm(n=1000, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2))
group_B <- mvrnorm(n=1000, mu=c(10,3), Sigma=matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2))
dat <- rbind(cbind.data.frame(group_A, group="A"),cbind.data.frame(group_B, group="B"))
plot(dat[,1:2], xlab="x", ylab="y", col=dat[,"group"])
```

In this **first setting** you see a group separation in the variable x, in the variable y, and you will also see a separation in both principal components. *Hence, using the PCA we get the same result we got in the univariate case: the groups A and B have different values in the variables x and y.*

In a **second example** generated by myself, you do not see a separation in variable x, variable y, or in PC1 or PC2. Hence, although our common sense suggests that we can distinguish between the two groups based on x and y, *we do not observe this in the univariate case and the PCA doesn't help us either*:

```
# Second setting
group_A <- mvrnorm(n=1000, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2))
group_B <- mvrnorm(n=1000, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=matrix(c(10,-3,-3,2),2,2))
dat <- rbind(cbind.data.frame(group_A, group="A"),cbind.data.frame(group_B, group="B"))
plot(dat[,1:2],  xlab="x", ylab="y", col=dat[,"group"])
```

QUESTION: Is there a case in where the PCA helps us in extracting correlations or separations we would not see in the univariate case? Can you construct one or is this not possible in the two-dimensional case.

Thank you all in advance for helping me to disentanglie this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is mainly the result of a misunderstanding of what PCA does. It does't find clusters of data like, say, kmeans or DBSCAN. It projects n-dimensional data onto an orthogonal basis. Then it selects the top k dimensions (according to variance explained), where k < n.

So in your example, PCA doesn't know that group A was generated by some distribution and group B by another. It just sees the data in 2 dimensions and finds two principle components (from which you may or may not select 1). You might as well plot all 2000 data points in the same color.

**However**, if you wanted to use PCA in this instance, you would indicate that a 3rd dimension distinguishes between group A and group B. You could, for example, label group A +1 and group B -1 (or something that makes sense relative to the scale of the other dimensions). Then perform PCA on 3 dimensions, reducing to 2 or 1, depending on what the eigenvalues tell you about the variation explained.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn’t mean to use PCA for clustering. Yes, PCA doesn’t know about the groups/coloring. But I assumed these groups truly exist. They are basically the outcome Y (e.g. healthy/sick).I will ask my question differently: People use PCA regression (PCR) to discriminate between two groups (run PCA, then test Y ~ PC1, Y~PC2…). I dislike this approach: in general case, PCs are an uninterpretable mixture of all variables. So why use PCR? According to my understanding, you will find a discriminative PC only if you already find a discriminative variable in the univariate setting